# PHP session & cookies, not existing

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I am working on a project, and I got a strange bug with sessions & cookies with PHP.

For use interfaces, I save some messages in session (like, "Operation have been done"). It is usefull for put some messages after a redirect.

It has worked nicely.

And yesterday, I found that it is bugging actually, both on my computer for dev, and on the production server.

So, I search for what the bug is ...
And I can not find what the problem is. I think it is really strange.

So here we are.
Any page reload, or change, the SESSID in the cookie is changing.
So of course, the variable `$_SESSION` is an empty array.
The data I want to store are nicely store in files `/var/lib/php5/sess_`, I check it.

So I try to see if there are some troubles with `$_COOKIE`, and there are.

I put this in the class which handle SessionMessage :

```
class SessionMessage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
        $retour = setcookie('lala', 'lulu', time() + 3600);
        var_dump($retour);
        var_dump($_COOKIE);
    }
 ...
 }
```

And here is the strangest part.
The browser remain the cookie (both PHPSESSID & lala).
The variable `$retour` worth `true`.
But the super-global `$_COOKIE` does not exists : the error is : `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: _COOKIE in <b>/home/vk/Prog/mvs/src/core/sessionmessage.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />`

Have someone an idea ?

Thank you,

Edit:
so I was thinking, it whould be a configuration of server.
But I am sure to not have change the conf of the production. And on dev, I have lot of projects, which handle session without any trouble.

And it is not about browser, I try on firefox and chrome and chromium.

Comment: Cookies you set aren't available until the _next_ request.

Comment: I know, and same-o same-o.

The main problem is not a notice: undefined index BUT notice: undefined variable. If you read well my post, you would see that I try to var_dump the whole COOKIE and not a specific one.

Comment: `setcookie`  add a header `Set-cookie` to response. `$_COOKIE` represents current request's cookies. You can manually add new setted cookies to `$_COOKIE` and/or declare `$_COOKIE = array()` if not exists.

Comment: @vekah What exact version of PHP is this on?

Comment: Production server : 5.4.44
Dev server : 5.5.9

Comment: If you put 'session_start()' in constructor, you'd better check whether it is started already. And the problem  looks similar to the one what I have met once,  do you clear old session and create a new session on some scenario? In that case, you need to ensure the new session id is sent to the client before setting data. you can use session_regenerate_id () to force it.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is a superglobal and is always defined. Does `$ php -r "var_dump(\$_COOKIE);"` yields the same notice?

Comment: On CLI in prints `array(0){} as expected`
That is what is the most strange @AlexBlex

Comment: @Jacob I think about it. I will do some singleton in the future.
Anyway I have checked and the constructor is only called once, and I instanciate only one time this class :)

Comment: Good, at least it is not something fundamentally broken. I'd suggest to make the same test via browser: a plain page with only `<?php var_dump(\$_COOKIE);` called directly. If it outputs the same empty array, then `$_COOKIE` is explicitly unset somewhere in your code before  `SessionMessage` is invoked.